# C# When Sending with PostAsync a JSON "Plain" magically appears on top of my JSON on receiver side

Tags: c#, json, post

I am trying to post a JSON with some color values in C#, this is the Code:

```
dynamic led = new JObject();
led.R = 55;
led.G = 55;
led.B = 55;
Console.WriteLine(led);
var postBody = new StringContent(led.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII, "application/json");
Console.WriteLine(postBody);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/update", postBody);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

The WriteLn outputs the following:

```
{
  "brightness": 55,
  "red": 139,
  "green": 141,
  "blue": 144
}
```

But at the backend my Server receives the following:

```
plain: {
   "brightness": 55,
   "red": 139,
   "green": 141,
   "blue": 144
}
```

I use the Newtonsoft JObject. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the way I was creating the JSON I could sent this request. But I still don't know why the other way doenst work. Here is the solution

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>  {
  { "red", rgb.R.ToString() },
  { "blue", rgb.B.ToString() },
  { "green", rgb.G.ToString() },
  { "brightness", "127" }
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/update", content);
return response.StatusCode;
```

By replacing the JObject with a Dictionary.